# iPhone: Camera Overlay can fit in a Tabbar Viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, camera, uitabbar

I have a Tabbar application, where clicking on a tabbar item, i should show a Camera Overlay view , BUT it should not HIDE the tabbar, Camera overlay should just fit into the tabbar viewcontrollers, just like behind the tabbar view. I created a custom camera overlay and called UIImagePickerController to my customer camera overlay. But it opens up with full screen mode and hides my tabbar etc.

```
pickerController.cameraOverlayView = camCumtomOverlay;
```

I even tried resized the custom camera overlay to small like below, but it open up the camera view with full screen and hides my entire tabbars.

```
myOwnOverlay = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)] autorelease];
```

But i want to to fit that custom camera overlay into tabbar.
Could someone please advise me how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're using `presentModalViewController:` to present the picker. Modal view controllers will go over everything that's behind, so the tabbar will hide as well. You can add a tabbar in the overlay that acts the same as the main tabbar.

Comment: Yes i code like this-> [self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];

Comment: Can anyone explain me? No other way showing UIImagePickerController custom camera overlay apart from presentModalViewController, which is causing me to full screen view?

Comment: I believe this is the only option if you want your application on apple store. Instead of trying to make the picker smaller I believe it's better to add a tabbar in your overlay and make it act as the main tabbar. By doing this the visual aspect should be about the same as making the picker smaller.